# Find the way back to the safe mode

Tags: account-security

I use MAC OS operation system that I frequently connect to my iPhone, I use Gmail, my university e-mail service, my university personal space, and numerous other websites that require log-in.

I know that I've been hacked, someone has full control over my computer, not in GUI way, but that person can delete files and create files. If he/she access to anything else I really can't say.

My solution is to change my computer, buy a new one and I won't try to do any information exchange happen between my new computer and the old one. But I still need to use my university account, e-mails, Gmail and my account on the websites, and I still need to use my iPhone.

Is this enough to guarantee the cybersecurity against that specific person ? or I need to change my phone, emails, and everything?

Here is a screenshot that i've received from the hacker.
[image]

Comment: In information security, you need to form a _threat model_ in order to tell whether or not a given set of actions is sufficient. That is, you need to know who your adversary is, what their capabilities are, what they are after, etc. Without knowing that, there's no way to answer. However, you can probably get away with just changing all your passwords (consider using a password manager).

Comment: @forest I wish i knew all the answers to your question, but i don't so i have to roll with the worst case scenario. I don't know if changing my passwords can prevent someone controlling my computer. Btw i want to use the same network, router.

Comment: How exactly do you know you've been hacked?

Comment: @forest i've got a message from the person, i see files coming and going,

Comment: @forest i use python for statistical analysis, i believe i ran a code by an accident, usually i don't read all the codes when i'm tired, i just run the program to see the results.

Comment: And the message told you that this person hacked you?

Comment: @forest yes, the person describes the next action, and the action happened, i received a screenshot, i update my question.

Comment: Ah, you have indeed been hacked. They are using the popular Metasploit framework. Run an antivirus scan. If it turns up nothing, re-install your operating system. And don't run random programs again. I'll write an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like they used the popular Metasploit framework to hack you. Everything you do on your computer between the time they hacked you and now is available to the attacker. I suggest you run an antivirus scan to remove the malware. If it turns up nothing, you should re-install your operating system. It's very unlikely that you need to buy an entire new computer. It takes a far more advanced hacker than the screenshot is showing to persist malware even after the system was re-installed.

Any account you logged into while your system was hacked should be considered compromised. Change the passwords for all of those accounts, and don't run random programs again. If you kept credit card or debit numbers on your computer, consider alerting your bank.